# Foreman 1.5 installation. Empty admin password, no login

Tags: login, installation

I've just installed foreman 1.5 from rpm on centos 6.5 and I get the login webpage but the default admin user doesn't work.

The password hash is empty and I get the following during installation:

```
/Stage[main]/Foreman::Database/Foreman::Rake[db:seed]/Exec[foreman-rake-db:seed]: Failed to call refresh: /usr/sbin/foreman-rake db:seed returned 1 instead of one of [0]
/Stage[main]/Foreman::Database/Foreman::Rake[db:seed]/Exec[foreman-rake-db:seed]: /usr/sbin/foreman-rake db:seed returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

I've read something about domain, the hostname is management.s so it gets s as domain. I don't know if this has something to do.